# un-style some component

Tags: html, css

i am using a definitive style for my  tags. now there is one  tag that i do not wish to appear that way. how do i do it?

Comment: what do you mean definitive style for your tags.

Comment: i mean i have made the style for the <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Give that one tag an ID, and then make a style for that specific ID.  It will override the style you set for the "a" tags.

Answer (score 0):

First, figure out the class or id of the element you want to change the style of using tools like **[firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843)**. Once you have found its class or id, search for it in the style sheet and modify the style as you like. If it still does not work, try appending the `!important` to your style, for example:

```
.myelement
{
  color: #ff0000 !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

The `!important` will override any pre-defined styles.

Comment: If you are very specific in your rule (e.g. `a .myelement`) you won't even need `!important`. Avoid `!important` where you can, it makes maintenance of complex CSS style sheets a nightmare. Override styles by specificity instead.

Comment: !important does not work. i used it on font-weight and color CSS properties. no effect. as ~Pekka suggested I ended up using a specific attribution

Comment: @Pekka: agreed but without the questioner's code shown I could suggest only this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't always reliably "unstyle" an element. For some style properties setting the value to `auto`, `default` or `none` will work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            a { background: pink; }
            a.normal { background: none; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="#">link1</a>
        <p><a href="#" class="normal">link2</a>
        <p><a href="#">link3</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

But not for example `color`. Replace `background` in above example by `color`. It won't work. You'll really need to force the color yourself, e.g. `color: blue`.